# Par 7 in golf hole?

Tags: trivia, golf

I know that there are many par 6 holes in golf courses and is Par 6 the highest for a hole?

Does any golf course have par 7 hole in the world?

Comment: -1: Google "golf par 7" brings up as much information as anybody could need or want.

Comment: [This recent answer to a different question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/14263) mentions this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The Satsuki golf course in Sano, Japan. It's 964 yards long and is par 7.  More info [here](http://www.yourgolftravel.com/19th-hole/2015/05/23/the-biggest-things-in-golf/2/)
2. Gunsan Country Club has a 1098 yards hole also par 7. More info [here](http://thegolfnewsnet.com/golfnewsnetteam/2014/09/07/photo-1100-yard-par-7-longest-golf-hole-world-7856/) and picture below
   [image: the course]

Comment: There, I can add more links if you want

Comment: I was going to post the two very same holes. AFAIK these are the only two par-7s in the world.