# Why are holes with par beyond 5 so rare?

Tags: golf

The vast, vast, *vast* majority of golf holes throughout the world are par-3, -4, or -5.  There are a smattering of par-6s, and, AFAIK, [only two par-7s *in the entire world* (both of them at Japanese country clubs)](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/14279/17690).

Given the huge variety of golf courses throughout the world, one would expect that this diversity would extend to their hole lengths, and that we'd see a lot more par-6s and par-7s, some par-8s and par-9s, and even a few holes with par 10, 11, 12, or higher.

Why are almost all of the world's golf holes clustered so tightly in the par-3-to-5 range, with so few longer than this?

Comment: I'm not much of a golfing enthusiast, so I'm hesitant to make this an answer, but I'd expect that space would have something to do with it. Golf courses are *huge* - each hole is hundreds of yards long, and there's 18 of them. It feels intuitive to me that, in the vast majority of cases, there's going to be a practical physical limit to how big the holes on a given course can be.

Comment: To some extent, golf courses want to keep players moving, so that more (paying) customers can tee off behind them. Having holes that can be *expected* to take longer to play decreases the "bandwidth" of the course.

Comment: Also, a par-10 isn't likely to be twice as challenging or twice as fun as a par-5, just twice as time-consuming.